# Why does my batch think that 09-01=-1?

Tags: batch-file, variables, math, dynamic, subtraction

So what I'm trying to do is create a dynamic variable that will eventually become the latest file to download from a website. In my example, I'm trying to download "downloads.informais.com/updates/psn_basic_sqlite_r4_20170531.exe" through an automated process. The r is the revision number, and the date is, well, the date. So here is what I have now:

```
@echo off
::http://downloads.informais.com/updates/psn_basic_sqlite_r4_20170531.exe
echo Dates > Dates.txt
::Get Variables
    set num=11
    set /a "num=num-1"
::: Begin set date
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
goto :end_set_date
:set_date
if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
goto :eof
:end_set_date
::: End set date
set PSN=psn_basic_sqlite_r%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%
set download=http://downloads.informais.com/updates/%PSN%.exe
GOTO TryPSNdownload

::Get the latest download
    :TryPSNdownload
    ::Fix Days
    if %dd%==9 set dd=09
    if %dd%==8 set dd=08
    if %dd%==7 set dd=07
    if %dd%==6 set dd=06
    if %dd%==5 set dd=05
    if %dd%==4 set dd=04
    if %dd%==3 set dd=03
    if %dd%==2 set dd=02
    if %dd%==1 set dd=01
set /a "num=num-1"
set PSN=psn_basic_sqlite_r%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%
set download=http://downloads.informais.com/updates/%PSN%.exe
echo %download% >> Dates.txt
if exist "%download%" (
GOTO Download
    ) else (
        ::Fix Month
        if %mm%==9 set mm=09
        if %mm%==8 set mm=08
        if %mm%==7 set mm=07
        if %mm%==6 set mm=06
        if %mm%==5 set mm=05
        if %mm%==4 set mm=04
        if %mm%==3 set mm=03
        if %mm%==2 set mm=02
        if %mm%==1 set mm=01
        if %mm%==0 set mm=12
        if %dd%==0 set dd=33
if %num%==0 set /a "dd=dd-1"
if %dd%==0 set /a "mm=mm-1"
if %num%==0 set num=11

GOTO TryPSNdownload
    )

:Download
Echo %download%

pause
```

This is outputing the %download% variable to a txt file, so you can see what I'm talking about, but it comes out like this:

```
http://downloads.informais.com/updates/psn_basic_sqlite_r0_20170609.exe 
http://downloads.informais.com/updates/psn_basic_sqlite_r10_201706-1.exe 
http://downloads.informais.com/updates/psn_basic_sqlite_r9_201706-1.exe
```

I had a feeling it was an order of operations type thing, but I can't figure it out. I added the place to "fix" the dd variable, to keep it in double digits, prior to that it would count down properly, except that it wouldn't include the zero before single digit numbers. Any suggestions for how to fix?

Comment: You're doing
set /a "num=num-1"
So i'd say num is not set properly and thus you get num = -1

Comment: It's IMO wasted time to tamper around with date/t or %date% that's all locale/user settings dependant. There are hundreds of Q&A  dealing with using wmic to get dates in yyyyMMdd format or using vbs/powershell with adddays functions. Get leading zeroes by adding 100 to your number and substring variable to the last 2 places - also very common.

Comment: Because batch interprets a numeric string starting `0` as an **octal** string and `09` is not a valid octal number. The standard workaround is to prefix the value with `1`, perform the operation required, then use substringing to isolate the last (2) characters. Since the number now starts non-0, it's interpreted as decimal.

Comment: @Tofandel %num% is behaving the way it should though, it goes from 11 to 0 over and over. It's the %dd% variable that's giving me issues.

I'm trying this now
    if %dd% GTR 9 (set DD=%dd%) else (set DD=0%dd%)

but now I'm getting the reset to 33 too soon.

Comment: @Magoo how do I go about doing that? I tried `if %dd% GTR 9 (set DD=%dd%) else (set DD=0%dd%)` while keeping ' if %num%==0 set /a "dd=dd-1" ' but it doesn't seem to work for me, it just goes from 9 to 33 now.

Comment: @Pyrometheous You should do the substraction before the conditions

Comment: set dd=1%dd%      set /a dd = dd -1      set "dd=%dd:~-2%". sets `dd` to 109, 108, 08 respectively. Equally, to 103, 102, 02 or 128, 127, 27

Comment: @Magoo I'll keep that in mind for the future, I found a different way of getting it to work though, now I've gotta figure out how to download the URL if it exists, but I imagine that'll be the easy part (maybe).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing the PSN variable to include "0" before %dd% if "dd" was less than 10, and kept the other operations the same, and now it works :-)

```
    @echo off
::http://downloads.informais.com/updates/psn_basic_sqlite_r4_20170531.exe
echo Dates > Dates.txt
::Get Variables
    set num=11
    set /a "num=num-1"
::: Begin set date
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/-. " %%i in ('date /t') do (call :set_date %%i %%j %%k %%l)
goto :end_set_date
:set_date
if "%1:~0,1%" gtr "9" shift
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%m in ('echo,^|date') do (set %%m=%1&set %%n=%2&set %%o=%3)
goto :eof
:end_set_date
::: End set date
set PSN=psn_basic_sqlite_r%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%
set download=http://downloads.informais.com/updates/%PSN%.exe
GOTO TryPSNdownload

::Get the latest download
    :TryPSNdownload
    set /a "num=num-1"
    ::Fix Days
    if %dd% LSS 10 (set PSN=psn_basic_sqlite_r%num%_%yy%%mm%0%dd%) else (set PSN=psn_basic_sqlite_r%num%_%yy%%mm%%dd%)
set download=http://downloads.informais.com/updates/%PSN%.exe
echo %download% >> Dates.txt
if exist "%download%" (
GOTO Download
    ) else (
        ::Fix Month
        if %mm%==9 set mm=09
        if %mm%==8 set mm=08
        if %mm%==7 set mm=07
        if %mm%==6 set mm=06
        if %mm%==5 set mm=05
        if %mm%==4 set mm=04
        if %mm%==3 set mm=03
        if %mm%==2 set mm=02
        if %mm%==1 set mm=01
        if %mm%==0 set mm=12
        if %num%==0 set /a "dd=dd-1"
        if %dd%==0 set /a "mm=mm-1"
        if %dd%==0 set dd=33
        if %num%==0 set num=11
GOTO TryPSNdownload
    )

:Download
Echo %download%

pause
```